# Entity Framework (code first) design thinking with multiple types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm not sure if my way of approaching my entity design is just flawed, or whether I'm basically there, but need additional knowledge.

I am designing a tree like structure (recursive), described by nodes which can either be a new level in the tree, a file or a help article. Files and articles can be placed at multiple points in the tree, so the file and article nodes are essentially pointers to content.

The nodes are described as:

```
public class Node
{
    public Enum NodeType
    {
        Node,
        File,
        Article
    };

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}

    public NodeType Type {get;set;}
    public int TypeId {get;set;}

    public virtual Node Parent {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Node> Children {get;set;}
}
```

From this, you have a table of nodes, indicating their parent (position in the tree), and what type they are. If they are a `File` or `Article` then the `TypeId` is a pointer into the two content tables:

```
public class File
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public byte[] Content {get;set;}
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

There is no problem doing this and you get what you would expect. What bugs me is that in the `Node` class, I have `virtual` parameters to get to the parent and children nodes, which in turn employ foreign keys to do the work and so it is very easy (i.e. no code required) to go from any `Node` up or down levels.

It would seem then that my design should allow me to add something similar to the `Node` class to allow easy access to the content object, such as:

```
public virtual Article Article {get;set;}
```

or

```
public virtual File File {get;set;}
```

But this seems wrong, as you would have to add a new virtual per possible type.

The other way would be to have both the content tables types inherit from some base type that allows you to add only one virtual:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id {get;set}
}

public class File : Base
{
    public byte[] Content {get;set;}
}

public class Article : Base
{        
    public string Content {get;set;}
}

// Node class then gets
public virtual Base Base {get;set;}
```

However, now you don't actually have access to the content unless you do a cast (which you have to figure out yourself from the type).

Am I on the wrong path, or nearly there?

Answer (score 0):

First way requires from you supporting logical pointers. That means that you can't simple delete your `File` object, you must find and delete corresponding `Node` objects. Most of the time, that's a bad idea. But if you have a framework for such "logical" relations, or you want to create one, it can be very handy.

From my experience, second way is the right one. You need to check a type of `Base` object if it is a `File` or `Article` but that's fast and legal operation.

You can also consider making `FileNode : NodeBase` and `ArticleNode : NodeBase` classes with typed references to `File` and `Article`, but in many scenarios type checking can still be required.

What is neccessary to understand is that polymorphism is not supported by relational models as in object models. So, every call to a navigation property of non-concrete type will cost you many sequential requests to all tables that can hold a derived type data. Usually, it is the bottleneck.

Comment: When I create the structures, by making the `Node` class abstract and then defining 3 seperate subclasses, the `Node` table ends up having two extra columns `Article_Id` and `File_Id`, which are used in FK's to the `Id` of the relevant content table (there is also a `Discriminator` column used to decide which subclass to use). The problem is that when I add content nodes, the `Article_Id` and `File_Id` columns are always `null`. There is no apparent tie between the `TypeId` column (from my original post) and the content. Code: http://pastie.org/10112152, Node SQL: http://pastie.org/10112158